# Adding Text to an Image in Django 2

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I have added text to image using PIL in a python script.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
image = Image.open('my_img.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
myfont = ImageFont.truetype("calibrib.ttf", 40)
points = 20,20
string = "My text for my_img.png"
draw.text(points, string, "black", font=myfont  )

image.save('my_img_WithTxt.png')
image.show()
exit()
```

I was hoping to use the above script in Django when I am uploading images to the media folder.  The script below works fine for uploading and retrieving images.

```
def create_room(request):

if request.method=='POST':
    form = RoomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/core/roomlist')
else:
    form =RoomForm()

return render(request, 'create_room.html', {
    'form':form
})
```

The issue I have is that before I execute 'form.save()', I want to write some text on the image.  Is there a way to extract the image field from 'request.FILES before saving it, write the text on image and then save it.

Comment: Django uploads can be memory-only or in a temporary folder.  It's easiest to save the form so the file is in MEDIA_ROOT and then make your modifications to the file afterwards.  You can load the image and save to the same file to avoid having to modify the database (as the path to the image would remain the same).

Comment: Thanks That sounds simple and straightforward